# Why LDO regulator rejected ripple better than normal Linear regulator

Tags: voltage-regulator, linear-regulator

Both type contain feedback loop but different type of output transistor .
Linear regulator use BJT
LDO use FET (which can operate at lower dropout voltage)
But what make LDO better noise rejection?

Comment: What makes you conclude that an LDO has a higher ripple rejection than a "normal Linear regulator"? Are you sure you're making a **fair comparison** and not comparing a **modern LDO** to for example an LM7805 which uses **old technology**?

Comment: I would state that actually the opposite is true: a regulator that is not "low drop" (an LDO is a low drop regulator) can be designed such that is has a **higher** ripple rejection. Reason: there is a larger voltage difference between input and output which means there is more voltage headroom to implement a better regulator. I have designed (non LDO-) regulators and LDOs and if you want a high ripple rejection, the non LDO regulator can always berform better.

Comment: Exactly which devices are you comparing to come to that conclusion?

Comment: Your question is fatally flawed in that it contains an assertion that is untrue.

Comment: Well it may be true for sufficiently low input voltages where the ripple causes the normal regulator to drop out.

Comment: Wow, I reallize that I was tricked by comercial advertisement video....

Comment: If you look at the graphs on LDOs, you'll find that even they have better performance across the board (except for heat) with a more overhead input voltage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDO (high-dropout regulators) versus LDOs... I'll use positive regulators only for the sake of simplicity...

Both can be made with BJTs or FETs, hell you could even use JFETs, vacuum tubes or whatever pass device is suitable for the job. Here's a PNP based LDO.

[image]

Tradeoffs are what you'd expect: BJTs require base current, so a PNP-based LDO will throw away some current into ground whereas a PMOS LDO will not, which makes the PMOS option more efficient, especially at low dropout where the PNP begins to saturate and requires more base current. However, at low dropout voltages, MOSFETs are quite a bit slower than BJTs, and parasitic capacitance increases, so there's a compromise.

Positive LDOs traditionally use P (PNP or P-channel) devices because that's simpler. But you can make a positive LDO with a N device too if you have a higher bias voltage available, or are willing to pack a charge pump. For example, say you have some 1.5V for your CPU, and you need some 1.2V at 1A for your FPGA or whatever. You could use a switcher, but you could also use a LDO, with that voltage drop that would still be pretty efficient. Problem: the chip needs a pass transistor which will fully turn on at 1.2V gate drive and pass the required current with a low dropout. For a PMOS this is a difficult combination. Even worse if you want 1V output. Also the whole drive circuit has to fit in the output voltage, and the internal error amp and reference have to work with the input voltage. Not easy with 1.5 volts. Solution is a [NMOS based LDO](https://www.diodes.com/design/support/technical-articles/ultra-low-dropout-ldos-provide-the-perfect-regulation-for-a-wide-range-of-devices/) which uses an additional higher voltage to power itself and drive the pass transistor.

[image]

> But what make LDO better noise rejection?

Mostly the fact that LDOs are more modern, whereas oldskool high-dropout regulators are more ancient.

PSRR depends on two things:

- At high frequency, how much parasitic capacitance there is across the pass device. More capacitance means more noise gets through. So a larger device, capable of more current, will be worse. P-channel will be worse. And since capacitance of transistors increases as Vds or Vce decreases, low dropout will be worse.
- At lower frequency where the feedback loop is regulating, PSRR depends on how the characteristics of the pass device depend on dropout voltage, and how much feedback is available to correct these variations.

For example, at low Vgs a MOSFET begins to turn into a resistor so it has strong dependence of Id versus Vgs, so it will need a stronger gate drive to keep Id where it needs to be. BJTs also get slower close to saturation. On the other hand, at higher dropout voltage, the pass device behaves much better and is faster and easier to drive.

All this means that the PSRR performance of any regulator will degrade at low dropout voltage, no matter the polarity of the pass device. This is not visible in high-dropout regulators, but in LDOs it is something the datasheets usually say... without saying it to clearly, because "more bigger numbers sell".

SO the answer to your question is:

1. LM317 was developed in 1976. Sure, modern regulators can have higher PSRR. This is not due to being LDO or not, but to better IC technology, faster error amps, higher bandwidth, etc. Note many modern LDOs are much worse than LM317, because they compromise to optimize other stuff, like low quiescent current. LM317 uses a huge quiescent current.
2. For any regulator, no matter the topology, PSRR is worse at low dropout. Modern LDOs get good performance **in spite of** low dropout because technology has advanced a lot.

Example: ADP151, a pretty good low noise regulator. Graphs at 2.8V out, 3.3V or 3.5V input. So dropout is 0.5 or 0.7V.

[image]

Notice the two curves at 10mA are quite similar. However, at 200mA, with the higher 3.5V input, PSRR begins to degrade above 1kHz. And at 3.3V input, with 0.5V dropout, at 200mA it loses about 15dB PSRR over the whole low frequency range because it's running out of Vds for this current.

That's because it's a 200mA regulator, so the internal PMOS is sized for that. Using a larger PMOS would make it more expensive and slower, thus worse at 100mA.

So when you check PSRR numbers, always look at the curves, at what frequency, at what current, what output caps, and at what dropout it's actually measured. If the datasheet proudly says "50mV droput!!" but the PSRR curves are measured at 0.5V dropout, they'll look a lot worse at 50mV.

Answer (score 4):

> Linear regulator use BJT LDO use FET (which can operate at lower
> dropout voltage) But what make LDO better noise rejection?

Not all 'LDO' regulators use a FET. FETs usually provide lower *minimum* voltage drop, but some bipolar LDOs also have less than 0.1 V at low output current.

Apart from the obvious fact that an LDO provides ripple rejection at lower voltage drop, at voltages within the regulation range a FET may not be better - and is often *worse*. For example, here are graphs showing ripple rejection of the [LM7805](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm340.pdf?HQS=TI-null-null-mousermode-df-pf-null-wwe&ts=1603585908222&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.mouser.com%252F) and [MCP1727](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/21999b.pdf).

[image]

[image]

10 dB at 50 kHz is not good! The LM7805 gets over 50 dB at the same frequency, and beats the MCP1727 at all frequencies up to 100 kHz.